# Use an application as only app on an android device

Tags: android, user-interface, default, startup

I'm going to write an application for a special device. The device's OS is android and it connects to a TV with HDMI cable and has a remote control as input hardware.(Like a video player) I need these to be done:

- When the user works with it, it should not be clear that the OS is android.
- User could not access to the OS system options like "Action bar" or "Setting menu" or etc.
- My app be the default app of the system and it runs at start up before any other app even the launcher.

so,

1. How can I change the android boot logo ?
2. How can I set my app to be the default application? May I need to set it as launcher?
3. how can I disable all other android UI tools like launcher and action bar permanently? (even my application close they should not be shown)
4. May I need a rooted android ? and witch version has these possibilities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my answers and share it to others.

> How can I change the android boot logo ?

- In some devices there is a file in `system/media/bootanimation.zip`
  can be edited and replaced.(When creating zip file should choose
  `Store` in compresstion type.)
- In some devices there is a file in `system/etc/bootvideo` thats in
  MP4 file format simply can be replaced.

> How can I set my app to be the default application? May I need to set
>   it as launcher?

Yes, simply add `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` to first activity category in the manifest like this:

```
    <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".ActivityStarter">
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

> How can I disable all other android UI tools like launcher and action bar permanently? (even my application close they should not be shown)

Uninstall all other launcher on the device. also for notification bar you can remove `Android UI` in system apps. Note that be sure your app is running correctly and does not crash, if not you will lose access to the device.(I installed `ES Explore` on the device and run it with a hidden button in my app to access my android system tools.)

> May I need a rooted android ? and witch version has these possibilities ?

Yes. In this case I used Android 4.4.2 but think other versions would be so.

Answer (score 0):

Android 5.0 supports [pinning an app](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/ho-to-pin-apps-in-android-5-lollipop/). There's also an app called [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en) that may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I want.I need to set my app the main process of device not just pin it on somewhere like lock screen.